# RuntimeError: ERROR 010093: Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4

I have written a stand-alone Python script to perform an ExtractByMask operation on numerous raster files in ArcMap, that have a .bil extension format.  However, when I try to save my output, I get the following runtime error:

[image]

Below is what my code looks like currently:

```
    #Import necessary system modules
    import arcpy,os
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *

    #Location where raster (.bil) files are located.  
    arcpy.env.workspace=r"D:\Mike_Daily_PRISM_PPT_from_2007_through2016\
    2007_Test"
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

    #Location where output files should go after "for" loop has completed.
    outws=r"D:\Mike_Daily_PRISM_PPT_from_2007_through2016\2007_Test\Output"

    #Location of the shapefile used to mask the PRISM raster(.bil) files
    mask=r"D:\Mike_Daily_PRISM_PPT_from_2007_through2016\2007_Test\
    MissouriBound.shp"

    #Only search for files that have .bil extension.  
    rasterlist=arcpy.ListDatasets("*.bil","Raster")

    #Print the list of raster files that have a .bil extension
    print rasterlist

    #for i in rasterlist, perform an ExtractByMask function on each raster.      
    for i in rasterlist:
    outExtractByMask=ExtractByMask(i, mask)
    outname=os.path.join(outws, str(i))
    outExtractByMask.save(outname)
```

I believe the error has something to do with the format that it's trying to save the output format raster with.  [Note:  Actually, I would prefer to save the output in a TIFF format (.tif).]  Can anyone confirm whether that is the issue with my code, and how I can then modify it to save the output with a .tif extension?

Comment: Please provide error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah the error is coming up because you're trying to export each masked raster as a BIL.  If exporting as a TIF is preferable anyway, it's an easy fix:

```
for i in rasterlist:
outExtractByMask=ExtractByMask(i, mask)
filename = str(i)[:-3] + 'tif'
outname=os.path.join(outws, filename)
outExtractByMask.save(outname)
```

Then it should run fine, exporting GeoTIFFs.  Obviously you can change that to match whatever raster format (supported by Arc) you might want.